# jQuery. Get tag + class name

Tags: jquery

I've got that html

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <input name="price" class="chrome-input" />
           </td>
           <td>
               <button name="sellButton" class="chrome-button">
               </button>
               <button name="priceButton" class="chrome-button">
               </button>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get `tr` that contains control with class `chrome-button` inside.
Something like this

```
alert($("tr+.chrome-button").html());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".chrome-button").closest('tr')
```

Comment: This should be the quickest as well since pseudo selectors are typically much slower.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
alert($("tr:has(.chrome-button)").html());
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NAdr4/

Comment: Thank you! That solved task. For education, I'd like to know, what if there is 10 <tr/> tags, how get first with that syntax $("tr:has(.chrome-button)")[0].html()

Comment: $("tr:has(.chrome-button)").eq(0)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("tr").children('td').each(function(){
    $(this).children('.chrome-button').each(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.parents()` method with a filter : http://api.jquery.com/parents/

```
alert($('.chrome-button').parents('tr').html())
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/tEWGW/